# directx audio video error message in debugmode

Tags: c#, winforms, video, audio, directx

I have a c#/winforms application that uses directx to play some video and audio.

whenever i start my application in debugmode i get this annoying message. i can click "continue" and everything seems to work fine. but i still want to get rid of this message. it does not show up in releasemode.

---

Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoaderLock' has detected a problem in 'C:\pathtoexe.exe'.
Additional Information: DLL 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://www.thezbuffer.com/articles/304.aspx) with managed DirectX (which is now discontinued). You can safely ignore it. Simply turn the MDA off in Visual Studio (goto Debug|Exceptions|Managed Debugging Assistants)